# excel vba can CurrentRegion give a specific selection?

Tags: excel

Hi I have the following lines of code

```
Sub selection()

'Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
'
Set rng = Range("A2").CurrentRegion
'rng.Delete
rng.Select


End Sub
```

It selects me all the cells that have information in that region, including the row of A1, but I don't want the first row to be selected, is there a way I can indicate to CurrentRegion that it should select all from A2 to all the cells that have information. And no I cannot specify a range because the information that is given in the cells I want to select is variable so it's not always the same length. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub selection()

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1, rng.Columns.Count).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```vb
Sub selection()

    ' To select current region without first column

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    rng.Offset(0, 1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count - 1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**